# How to retrain a TensorFlow lite Model for MLKit Object Detection on mobile? What Tensorflow Hub model do I choose to retrain?

Tags: android, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, android-camerax

I've been working on an Android app to use the CameraX API and I would like to create  an Image Analyzer using MLKit. My main objective is to detect a certain type of document of particular size, one detection label for the front and one for the back. So I would like to train a TensorFlow Lite model that can meet my particular needs. I've already seen lots of great documentation that describes just how I can use my own model locally on the phone for my Analysis use case so that isn't an issue.

Problem is I'm a mobile dev and I don't know much about actually training my model. I have a ton of training data as I've gone through some great tutorials like [like this one](https://medium.com/over-engineering/building-a-custom-machine-learning-model-on-android-with-tensorflow-lite-26447e53abf2) and I have a lot of images (thousands) of the documents to be classified, and I have organized them into their respective directories as described. I also followed along with [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mF-iqKqKQsY) and it is pretty apparent that using the TensorFlow Image Classifier and a trained model to retrain is a hugely beneficial approach, but I haven't seen much information on exactly *why* they have chosen that Tensorflow Hub lite model. What makes one better than the others, and what should I look for to pick the best one for retraining and fitting my particular needs (detecting a particular document)?

Is this the right approach? Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can refer to https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md